# Import python module to python script in databricks

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on a project in Azure DataFactory, and I have a pipeline that runs a Databricks python script. This particular script, which is located in the Databricks file system and is run by the ADF pipeline, imports a module from another python script located in the same folder (both scripts are located in in `dbfs:/FileStore/code`).

The code below can import the python module into a Databricks notebook but doesn't work when is imported into a python script.

```
sys.path.insert(0,'dbfs:/FileStore/code/')
import conn_config as Connect
```

In the cluster logs, I get:  `Import Error: No module named conn_config`

I guess that the problem is related to the inability of the python file of recognizing the Databricks environment. Any help?

Comment: You're right. This was an error.

Comment: That really took a while  Well, thanks anyway  PS: You should still go on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally get it done with spark. Once the Spark Session is created (if your cluster has the spark session integrated there is no need to initiate a session):

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("dbfs:/FileStore/code/conn_config.py")
import conn_config as C
```

This syntax can import a python module to a python script which is run from Azure DataFactory.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use path with `dbfs:` in it - Python doesn't know anything about this file system.  You have two choices:

1. Replace `dbfs:/` with `/dbfs/` (won't work on Community edition)
2. Copy file(s) from DBFS to local file system with `dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/FileStore/code", "file:/tmp/code", True)`, and refer to that local file name: `/tmp/code`

Comment: Is there any other option? I was thinking that may be is a way to refer to the python file my specific dbfs before giving the FileStore path.

Comment: you can upload files to any location on DBFS, or even have a separate ADLS container mounted to DBFS

Comment: @IspanCristi So does any of the given solutions work? If not, please *change your question* so that one can really see what you want to achieve and what requirements you have to comply with! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use `%run relative_path/file_name` then you can use the module right away, without import.

Comment: The issue with this is that it breaks the namespacing, this will quickly become problematic if you need to import multiple files. In my view it's a hacky workaround which you can use very carefully if you have to, but it's not what the question is asking for

Comment: Don't judge a thing so subjective. It really depends on your working environment, this works around method will help you if you are in an industry project which dbfs has been blocked for data privacy purpose like using immuta. In my case, above 2 method didn't work, but this solution helps me in my work, so I share it.

Answer (score -3):

You can just use references to filestores:

```
(0,'dbfs:/FileStore/code')
```